# How to make the headers of two fits files the same in IDL?

Tags: idl-programming-language, fits

I have to make the header of a fits file called 'exponential.fits' the same as the header of 'empirical.fits'. Is there any way to do it with writefits.pro?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with `writefits.pro` but you will end up overwriting the file that already exists so you may want to look into doing it with another program. But the way to do it using `writefits` (assuming you wanted the 0th extension header) would be:

```
; get the header you want and the data of the file you need
empirical_hdr = headfits('empirical.fits')         ;header
exponential_data = readfits('exponential.fits')    ;data

;overwrite the exponential.fits with what you want
writefits,'exponential.fits',exponential_data,header=empirical_hdr
```